# Where to save logback.xml file for use of Logger slf4j in Java

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have a question regarding the location where I should save my logback.xml file so that my program can find it. I now saved it in src/main/resources, but it cannot find it. I know this since

```
    String URL = "logback.xml";
    System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(URL));
```

returns `null`.

The logger does work, but prints all information to the command line

```
null
13:05:26.606 [main] DEBUG o.j.f.c.master.AbstractMaster - Number of columns: 18
13:05:26.613 [main] DEBUG o.j.f.c.master.AbstractMaster - Objective value: 479.0
13:05:26.666 [main] DEBUG o.j.f.c.master.AbstractMaster - Number of columns: 113
13:05:26.668 [main] DEBUG o.j.f.c.master.AbstractMaster - Objective value: 272.0
13:05:26.693 [main] DEBUG o.j.f.c.master.AbstractMaster - Number of columns: 118
13:05:26.694 [main] DEBUG o.j.f.c.master.AbstractMaster - Objective value: 238.0
13:05:26.721 [main] INFO  o.j.f.c.master.AbstractMaster - Best objective value found: 238.0
13:05:26.721 [main] INFO  o.j.f.c.master.AbstractMaster - (d1-s2-s2-d1) (s2-c1-s2) (s2-c3-c2- 
s2);238.0 chosen with value: 1.0 resulting in cost: 238.0
```

The content of my logback.xml file is

```
<configuration scan="true" info="true">
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
     <file>myApp.log</file>
  <append>false</append>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name="algorithms.MultiLabel.cg.master" level="OFF"/>

  <root level="debug"> <!-- levels: OFF, info, debug -->
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Next I make some changes to the logback.xml file and again save it in the src/main/resources folder. If I now run my program again, I suddenly get the following output.

```
file:./target/classes/logback.xml
13:06:41,631 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
13:06:41,631 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
13:06:41,632 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:./target/classes/logback.xml]
13:06:41,715 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
13:06:41,720 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[.\target\classes\logback.xml]] every 60 seconds. 
13:06:41,720 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
13:06:41,731 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender]
13:06:41,733 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]
13:06:41,783 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
13:06:41,783 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
13:06:41,783 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
13:06:41,783 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [myApp.log]
13:06:41,787 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
13:06:41,789 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
13:06:41,790 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
13:06:41,797 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [algorithms] to OFF
13:06:41,797 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
13:06:41,797 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
13:06:41,798 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
13:06:41,798 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
13:06:41,800 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@36f6e879 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

Best objective value found: 238.0
(d1-s2-s2-d1) (s2-c1-s2) (s2-c3-c2-s2);238.0 chosen with value: 1.0 resulting in cost: 238.0
```

- Why does it now find the file in the folder ./target (where the src folder also is located), even though I did not save it there?
- All information that it is printing is coming from the master package, which I set to "OFF", so how come it is still printing it?

I am looking forward to any suggestions/explanations!

Comment: All classes are compiled to the target folder and the resources are copied there as well. So probably the project wasn't build appropriately after you initially created the logback.xml. When you  made the changes, your IDE had probably rebuild the project and copied the same file in the /target folder. Regarding the second problem, I can't see any log lines from the master package.

Comment: Not all loggers will have OFF level, just because there was a call from a class in the master package.

Comment: @Nenad With regard to the first question, thank you for the explanation, I understand it now. With regard to the second question. If you look at the first output, you can see that "Best objective. .." and "(d1-s2-..." are on INFO level in the master file. In the last code screen, you can see that I set the ROOT to INFO, but the [algorithms]  to OFF. Since I only implemented the Logger in [algorithms] I would expect that no output would be printed, which is not the case, as you can see in the last two lines of the code block. How do I correctly specify the level for a given package?

Comment: I didn't notice that the last 2 lines belong to the master package, sorry. It looks like you're using the correct approach to specify OFF level for all loggers in the master package. Is it possible that you're maybe missing the package name (Is algorithms.MultiLabel.cg.master the correct package?). Did you move the AbstractMaster class to another package, since the abbreviated package name in the first log above doesn't look like it's matching (o.j.f.c.master.AbstractMaster).